# I don't understand what this means $ \sum_{i|h(x_i) = y_j} p_X (x_i) $

Tags: probability, notation

I was reading a book of probability and in the demonstration of:
$ E(h(X)) = \sum_{x\in R_x}h(X) \cdot p_X(x) $. The next step confused me, because I don't get what means the thing under the last summation:

$ E( Y = h(X) ) = \sum_{j}y_j \cdot p_Y(y_j) = \sum_{j}y_j \cdot \sum_{i|h(x_i) = y_j} p_X (x_i) $.

This means that you will sum over all $x_i|h(x_i) = y_j$ ?

Comment: The last sum is over just the $i$'s where $h(x_i)=y_j$ (though I dunno why it became $h$ when it was $g$ before).

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it.

Comment: You can read it as sum over all the i such that $h(x_i) = y_j$. In other words, all the $x_i$ in the support of X such that $h(x_i) = y_j$. Does that answer your question?